# If Statement Needs to Alert the Number That the User Enters

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, operators, dialog

I'm developing a simple javascript program that compares two numbers entered by a user. If the first number is greater than the second number, the dialog box should display "x is larger." If the second number is greater than the first number, the dialogue box should display "y is larger." Right now, the box is displaying "firstNumber is larger" instead of the actual number. How do I change my If statement so that the program will display the actual number that the user enters instead of the variable name?

If the numbers are equal, a writeln message will show up that says "These numbers are equal" (that part is working fine).

Thank you!

JSfiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/9m4ohdkj/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <title>Compare Numbers</title>
  <script>

     var firstNumber; // first string entered by the user
     var secondNumber; // second string entered by the user


     // enter first number from user as a string
     firstNumber = window.prompt( "Enter an integer" );

     // enter second number from user as a string
     secondNumber = window.prompt("Enter second integer");

     // convert numbers from strings to integers
     firstNumber = parseInt(firstNumber);
     secondNumber = parseInt(secondNumber);

     //determine result
     if ( firstNumber > secondNumber )
        window.alert("firstNumber is larger");

     if ( firstNumber < secondNumber )
        window.alert("secondNumber is larger"); 

     if ( firstNumber == secondNumber )
        document.write("These numbers are equal!")


     // end if

  </script>
  </head><body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your alert to take the variable name out of the string being shown, like so:

```
 window.alert(firstNumber + " is larger");
```

Similarly for the second variable. What's happening now is that your variable name is treated as a literal string (similar to the 'is larger' part) because it's inside double quotes, and so the alert *literally* shows 'firstNumber is larger'!

Comment: I didn't know you needed the double quotes to be considered a string. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's what you use for your literal strings. Note that you can use either double or single quotes for this.